# как в XML вытянуть url для проигрывания

Tags: wpf, xml, bass.net

Как вытянуть URL из stations.xml, для проигрывания в ListBox?

**stations.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stations>
  <station url="http://onair.eltel.net:80/europaplus-128k" id="0">EuropaPlus2</station>
  <station url="http://online.radiorecord.ru:8101/rr_128" id="1">RRadio</station>
  <station url="http://radio.kazanturl-fm.ru:8000/mp3" id="2">Kazanturl</station>
  <station url="http://stream.kissfm.ua:8000/kiss" id="3">Kiss FM</station>
  <station url="http://online.radiorecord.ru:8102/club_128" id="4">Radio Record</station>
  <station url="http://uk1.internet-radio.com:15614" id="5">Horizon FM</station>
  <station url="http://radio.bestfm.fm:8080/bestfm64" id="6">Best FM</station>
  <station url="http://uk3.internet-radio.com:10911/" id="7">Abc Christmas</station>
</stations>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Un4seen.Bass;
using Un4seen.Bass.AddOn.Tags;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

    namespace WpfApplication6
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            DOWNLOADPROC _downloadProc_ = null;
            private int handleSynchronization;
            SYNCPROC _syncProcChangeTags = null;
            private int numberStream = 120;
            private int volume = 100;
            string fileName = ("stations.xml");

            public MainWindow()
            {

                InitializeComponent();
                Bass.BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, IntPtr.Zero);
                LoadStations();

            }

        }

            public void Play (Uri address)
            {
                Bass.BASS_StreamFree(numberStream);  //освобождаем поток.
                handleSynchronization = Bass.BASS_ChannelSetSync(numberStream, BASSSync.BASS_SYNC_META, 0, _syncProcChangeTags, IntPtr.Zero);

                numberStream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateURL(address.OriginalString, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_STREAM_STATUS, _downloadProc_, IntPtr.Zero); //Bass.dll создаёт поток и возвращает его номер, для дальнейшего управления потоком, по его номеру
               if (numberStream != 0) 
                {
                    GetTagsFromURLStream(); 

                    Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(numberStream, true); //играем полученный поток начав сначала (второй параметр за это отвечает)
                    Bass.BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(numberStream, BASSAttribute.BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, this.volume);
                }
              else
                   MessageBox.Show(" ");
            }

            void GetTagsFromURLStream()
            {
                TAG_INFO tagInfo = new TAG_INFO();
                Bass.BASS_ChannelGetTags(numberStream, BASSTag.BASS_TAG_META);
                BassTags.BASS_TAG_GetFromURL(numberStream, tagInfo);

            }

            public void LoadStations()
            {
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
                    XmlNodeList stationNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//stations/station");
                    foreach (XmlNode stationNode in stationNodes)
                    {
                        string name = stationNode.InnerText;
                        listBox.Items.Add(name);
                    }
                    xmlDoc.Save(fileName);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Не найдены радиостанции.");
                }
            }



            private void mylistbox(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                int link = 0;
                Play(new Uri(listBox.SelectedItems[link].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чё-то у вас всё сложно, давайте сделаем попроще.

```
<Window x:Class="ТутВашеПространствоИмён.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="src" Source="stations.xml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src}, XPath=//stations/station}"
             Name="Box" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.PlayCommand, ElementName=Box}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding XPath=@url, Path=Value}"
                            DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Play now"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=.}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Получится вот такой UI:

[image: пример UI]

Как вы уже видите, вам нужна VM, в которой будет определена команда `PlayCommand`. Это просто:

```
class ExampleCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing: " + parameter);
    }
}

class VM
{
    public VM() { PlayCommand = new ExampleCommand(); }
    public ICommand PlayCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Не забудьте установить экземпляр `VM` `DataContext`'ом вашего окна.